# Sending Email to Server on Domain

Tags: email, tcp, windows-server-2008

I have been asked to handle an email being generated from an application on the company network. This is not going via exchange, the app has sends SMTP itself. TO capture the email on the receiving server I intend to write a windows service to listen on Port 25.

The questions is how to get the data on to the receiving server. The network admin thinks sending [name]@[server] will work internally. Is this the case?

This may well by the wrong place to ask as I don't need help with the code, just getting the email to the right place.

Many Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I think the appropriate place is serverfault.com

Comment: Didn't know about serverfault.com, will use there. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app generating the email has settings for either a "SmartHost" or an "SMTP Gateway" then I would recommend setting the IP of the receiving server there and avoiding potential problems with DNS.

If not, then yes, you should be able to say user@hostname. If there are no MX records set for the hostname, then RFC says you should fall back and use A records, and so the sender should send the mail on port 25 directly to the hostname.

You can check to see if your server is accepting connections on port 25 and mail commands by using our [SMTP Diag tool](http://bit.ly/Yi2NqR) if you like.